# iOS structured concurrency - How can i use Sendable to stop strict concurrency warnings

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, concurrency, swift-concurrency

In the class below, I get the following warning `Capture of 'self' with non-sendable type 'TestClass' in a '@Sendable' closure"`

I realise i could conform `TestClass` to `Sendable` in this example, but in my actual app that feels problematic as it would mean significant more changes making everything in the class conform to Sendable.

Given there is no state changes in my example below, is there a simple `@Sendable` i'm missing on the function or Task closure to suppress the warning?

```
final class TestClass {
    
    func doA() {
        Task {
            await MainActor.run {
                doB() // ⚠️ WARNING ⚠️: Capture of 'self' with non-sendable type 'TestClass' in a `@Sendable` closure"`
            }
        }
    }
    
    func doB() {
        print("blah")
    }
}
```

**Note**:

Using strict concurrency checking, found in: *Build Settings > Strict Concurrency Checking > Complete*

Comment: Why introduce `Task` in the first place, your floating `Task` is a setup for a race condition.

Comment: Unrelated, but if B must run on the main actor, we’d generally decorate it with `@MainActor` and lose `MainActor.run {…}`. Or if this was a class that was inextricably tied to the main thread (e.g., a view model, a type using run loop based objects like `Timer` or `CLLocationManager`, etc.), we’d mark the whole class as `@MainActor`. It’s impossible to advise on the broader issue of why you’d do this on the basis of the limited information provided thus far.

Comment: In short, there’s no simple way to silence this error correctly. Basically, this class is accessed from multiple threads and the compiler wants to ensure thread-safety. In your example, there is no mutable state, so adding `Sendable` conformance is trivial, but you suggest that making the whole class thread-safe is non-trivial. Solutions range from (a) putting the whole type on the main actor to (b) making B a `static` func to (c) abstracting the thread-safe stuff into a separate object. A slightly more practical example of the problem would help immensely.